# Button click event firing twice only on Edge browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, microsoft-edge

I have a strange problem with our ASP.NET web application in Microsoft Edge.

When clicking a button, the click event was called twice also the page init and pag load. The button has handles btn.ServerClick

This only happens on Microsoft Edge. Other browsers like Chrome, IE8-IE11, Safari are working okay. I'm using Microsoft Edge 20.10240.16384.0 and 20.10240.17146.0

Did any of you experience similar problem? What causes the problem and how did you able to fix this?

I reproduced the problem.

**This is my mark-up code for the button:**

```
<button id="btn" runat="server">HTML button Save</button>
```

**This is the external Javascript:**

```
var trigger = new trigger_class();
function trigger_class() {  
}

trigger_class.prototype.postback = function(ctrl_id) {
    __doPostBack(ctrl_id,'');

    return true;
}

var track = new track_class();
function track_class() {
}

track_class.prototype.do_something = function(ctrl_id, ctrl_client_id) {
    //do something
    trigger.postback(ctrl_id);
}
```

**This is the vb code:**

```
Partial Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub page_init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
   '-->Set something
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      '-->Set something
End Sub

Protected Sub control_prerender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
     Me.btn.Attributes.Item("onclick") = "return track.do_something('" & Me.btn.UniqueID & "', '" & Me.btn.ClientID & "');"

End Sub

Private Sub btn_click(ByVal ao_sender As Object, ByVal ao_event_args As EventArgs) Handles btn.ServerClick
     '--> validate and save
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I have seen similar problem but not sure on the cause and fix.

Comment: I already fixed my problem.
There are two possible fix that I tested and is working okay:
 1) Add type="button" attribute on the button tag
 2) Use "return false;" for the javascript function postback

Answer (score 0):

just use an `event.stopPropagation();`
this will stop the click's propagation before the next trigger is called